# Graphql query, navigate, map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a Graphl query and a submit form on the homepage.
I'd like that if I click on the submit button it starts to make the query, navigate me onto the second page and I'd like to map the results there.
What should I use for this?

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself. 
Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), 
read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and 
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You can't do both things at same time. Please execute the query first and once executed and you have the data. Use `useNavigate` from react-router-dom to navigate to other route with that data. You can pass the data like this in useNavigate: `useNavigate('/componentS' ,{ state: { name: "something" }})`

Comment: @kazmi066 how do you access the state in the next component when passing with `useNavigate`?

Comment: @よつば through `useLocation()` in react-router-dom